# How to set up p:datatable width?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I set p:datatable width?
I was trying to enclose p:datatable in an outer div with width but this has no effect. Also I was trying set width to generated `table` tag but this also has no effect. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Start by reading the PrimeFaces docs and look at the showcase..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of the datatable by adding some css, to achieve that you can use the attribute **STYLE**, something like this

```
<p:dataTable id="dt" value="#{yourBean.list}" var="car" style="width:85%;" >
</p:dataTable>
```

PS : you can use also a pixel value instead of %